# Is it possible to run two javascript libraries, MooTools for Selectervizr, jQuery for everything else?

Tags: jquery, mootools, integration

Selectervizr works best with MooTools but the site I am building uses jQuery. How can I make Selectervizr work at its best without just moving completely over to MooTools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you most definitely can.

Mootools and jQuery both offer a kind of non conflict mode which allow you to use both frameworks by freeing up any ties.

jQuery : [jQuery No Conflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

MooTools : [MooTools $ safe mode](http://mootools.net/blog/2009/06/22/the-dollar-safe-mode/)

**Just to note: only one of the above is required.*

Comment: I was aware of the no-conflict, but I wasn't sure if I have to set it. Basically I will not be using MooTools, Selectervizr will be. Selectervizr says it just picks the best library, and to included a number if needed. Just not sure if there are problems with this or not

Comment: basically you would need to call `noConflict()` on jQuery since Selectervizr will be using MooTools. In our environment we have something similar which we just call `var $j = jQuery.noConflict();` mooTools and jQuery (called with $j) reside happily together.

Answer (score 1):

I believe JQuery has a 'noconflict' mode - perhaps enable that on the scripts where you need to use mootools/JQuery on the same page.

That has done the trick for me a number of times.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but you should have this in mind: both libraries are "quite big".

jquery have setup so release `$` to another library: http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

I think mootools also has that. but its enough to change the jquery setup with noConflict

Answer (score 0):

Use  [`.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="mootools.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
  });
  //$ is free for any library to use here
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Both jQuery and mootools have a noConflict (See [this](http://mootools.net/blog/2009/06/22/the-dollar-safe-mode/) and [this](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries)) mode. You can wrap your code in a function if you want to keep the dollar sign:

```
(function($){
    //your mootools code
})(document.id);

(function($){
    //your jQuery code
})(jQuery);
```